# Не линкуются вопросы по внутренним ссылкам

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено

В [вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483157/178988) есть ссылка на другой вопрос в виде

```
[переопределение `ProcessCmdKey`](/a/480925/178988)
```

но вопрос с тем ответом не становится связанным.

Недавно сталкивался с такой же ситуацией на мете - решил правкой на абсолютную ссылку.